# Test code for my ODE says it is wrong, while I have proof it's right

Tags: scipy, ode

I am following [this tutorial](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/LoktaVolterraTutorial.html) on a Lokta Volterra (Predator-prey) problem. I managed to product a plot that looks like theirs. However, I want a definitive proof that my implementation is correct.

My first idea is to calculate `rabbits[t]-rabbits[t-1]` and compare with the analytical equation of the number of rabbits to see if they are the same. However I cannot make the test code work.

The test code

```py
def test(rabbits, foxes, ts, t):
    '''
    rabbits, foxes, ts: array of numbers of rabbits, foxes and time points
    t: a specific timestep (t < len(ts))
    '''
    calculated_drabbit_dt=(rabbits[t+1]-rabbits[t]) 
    analytic_drabbit_dt=a*rabbits[t]-b*rabbits[t]*foxes[t]  # equation is also in link above, rabbit is called u
    print([calculated_drabbit_dt], [analytic_drabbit_dt])
    assert np.isclose([calculated_drabbit_dt], [analytic_drabbit_dt])

test(rabbits_2, foxes_2, t, t=166)
```

Why did I do wrong in my test code?

Comment: It's difficult to check without knowing the values of the arrays `rabbits_2`, `foxes_2` and the timesteps array. Please provide some dummy values or code to generate those arrays. Also the use of the variable `t` both as 3rd and 4th argument in the function is confusing (although not wrong per se).

Comment: Your finite difference approximation `calculated_drabbit_dt` must be divided by Δt to be an approximation of the actual instantaneous derivative in `analytic_drabbit_dt`.  Try something like `calculated_drabbit_dt = (rabbits[t+1]-rabbits[t]) / (ts[t+1] - ts[t])`.  And don't forget that `calculated_drabbit_dt` is a finite difference *approximation*, so you can't expect the values to be exactly the same.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I see. Decreasing the number of ∆t by 100 times brings very small difference. Do you know of any other test I can do?